# Vue Js not displaying

Tags: vue.js, symfony

This is my very beginning with Vue with Symfony. Problem is nothing is displayed in my page, I was expecting `Hello` to be print. I did all my configurations. I have created folder `vue`

Inside vue I have following 2 files.

### App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

### index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";

new Vue({
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
}).$mount("#app");
```

I have in my `webpack.config.js`

```
.addEntry('app', './assets/vue/index.js')
```

I did anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mounting the Vue instance to something existing in the DOM with id `app`. But the component inside `App.vue` also contains a div with id `app`. Try to mount to anything else on the page that Symfony creates (you can't mount on body or html). I'm sure that page does not contain anything with id `app`.

Comment: Thanks Ferry, First time with Vue so getting difficulties